# how to use JNativeHook library?

Tags: java, hook, libraries, keystroke

I am trying to use the JNativeHook library in my project so I can get the global keystrokes, but I am not sure how to import or install the library in my project. I need help on importing the library to my project. I need simple steps to install the library as I am new to java programming.

Comment: Which IDE are you using? Are you using Maven? Usually you simply use the .jar.

Answer (score 2):

With Eclipse, `right click on project > properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > Add JARs`... Then add jnativehook.jar